# Rust complaining about borrowing after scope

Tags: rust, linked-list, borrow-checker

I am trying to create a linked list in Rust, and to append values in the end, I need to traverse it and then add this new value. Im avoiding recursion, as in large lists it would be bad, plus trying to understand the Box logic better.

The problem is, after traversing, my variable 'current' is a mutable reference to the last node of the list. But I cant modify it, Rust complains about references that are **already** dropped at this scope.

```rust
struct Node {
    valor: Option<String>,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(valor: Option<String>) -> Node {
        Node { valor, next: None }
    }
}

struct NodeList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
impl NodeList {
    fn new() -> NodeList {
        NodeList { head: None }
    }
    fn append(&mut self, novo: Node) {
        if self.head.is_none() {
            self.head = Some(Box::new(novo));
        } else {
            let mut current: &mut Option<Box<Node>> = &mut self.head;
            loop {
                let after: &mut Option<Box<Node>> = &mut (current.as_mut().unwrap()).next;
                if after.is_none() {
                    break;
                } else {
                    current = after;
                }
            }
            current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(novo));
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lista = NodeList::new();

    for c in "açafrão".chars() {
        let s = String::from(c);
        lista.append(Node::new(Some(s)));
    }
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*current` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src\main.rs:32:13
   |
25 |                 let after: &mut Option<Box<Node>> = &mut (current.as_mut().unwrap()).next;
   |                                                           ---------------- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
32 |             current.as_mut().unwrap().next = Some(Box::new(novo));
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             second mutable borrow occurs here
   |             first borrow later used here
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve the issue?

Comment: I would recommend this reading for learning the ins and outs of linked lists in rust: https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In think in your special case you ran into an unsolved corner case of the borrow checker. Your code will compile in the future, but currently doesn't.

More info about this can be seen here: https://docs.rs/polonius-the-crab/

To demonstrate that this is in fact the case, your code builds and works fine with the experimental (and not yet stable) `polonius` borrow checker:

```
RUSTFLAGS="-Zpolonius" cargo +nightly run
```

The best way to fix this in your case is to rearrange the order of the calls so the compiler understands them better, like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    valor: Option<String>,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(valor: Option<String>) -> Node {
        Node { valor, next: None }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct NodeList {
    head: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
impl NodeList {
    fn new() -> NodeList {
        NodeList { head: None }
    }
    fn append(&mut self, novo: Node) {
        if self.head.is_none() {
            self.head = Some(Box::new(novo));
        } else {
            let mut current: &mut Node = &mut self.head.as_mut().unwrap();
            loop {
                if current.next.is_none() {
                    current.next = Some(Box::new(novo));
                    break;
                }
                current = current.next.as_mut().unwrap().as_mut();
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut lista = NodeList::new();

    for c in "açafrão".chars() {
        let s = String::from(c);
        lista.append(Node::new(Some(s)));
    }

    println!("{:#?}", lista);
}
```

```
NodeList { head: Some(Node { valor: Some("a"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("ç"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("a"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("f"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("r"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("ã"), next: Some(Node { valor: Some("o"), next: None }) }) }) }) }) }) }) }
```

---

### *Side note:*

Don't try to learn Rust by implementing a linked list. Linked lists are highly incompatible with Rusts ownership model.

If you insist on doing it anyway, this article is absolutely mandatory for guidance:

https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/

Comment: Thanks! My endgoal is actually working with trees, so I started with a list to get the hang of Rust's "pointers".

Comment: @titoco3000 Sure :) single linked Boxed lists are also not much of a problem, as their ownership is still a tree. Rust gets problems with double linked lists, because ownership is no longer clear, and you have to do tricks with `Rc` and `Weak`. But `Box` based trees should be fine :) Although still not trivial; I was part of the implementation of `tokio_utils::ShutdownToken`, which is a tree based thing, and there were many problems :D especially concerning thread safety (more specifically deadlock safety).

Comment: If you are interested, you can see our thoughts and discussions here: https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/pull/4652
Maybe it helps your project, maybe not.